# Ajax Error - Wordpress

Tags: php, html, ajax, wordpress

the admin-ajax requests are being blocked on my server and I get the 404 error with bad request error message 
[image]

I re-installed wordpress, as well as tried different themes, and keep experiencing this error

i have also tried disabling all plugins

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

Comment: Have you checked the server settings?

Comment: @AqibAshef  is that something I can check in cPanel ? I am not having any joy with my host checking on the situation

Comment: See if there is some kind of filter to prevent js script loading. I have done this kind of stuffs in nginx but not in cpanel before.

Comment: the error occurs only, when you use page builder?

Comment: @SamvelAleqsanyan yes that is correct

Comment: do your page builder have backend part( change page from wp-admin without see how the page changes ) ? if yes, then try to change without view mode

Comment: @SamvelAleqsanyan   I tried using the backend of the page builder now, and got this error when updating the page : 
No Results Found
The page you requested could not be found. Try refining your search, or use the navigation above to locate the post.

"post.php" Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: what is your page builder name, version and wp version?

Comment: @SamvelAleqsanyan    Divi Builder - (Divi Version: 3.0.101) Wp Version: Version 4.9.4

Comment: I think, the priblem is with the version of builder. try to update it to latest version

Comment: @SamvelAleqsanyan Thank you. I have updated to the latest DIVI, but still have the same problem

Comment: another suggest: deactivate all plugins besides divi builder and try use it.  this may be some incompatible plugin

Comment: @SamvelAleqsanyan thank you. i have no plugin installed. divi builder is part of the divi theme. no other plugins installed

Comment: resave your permalinks. check server side errors. its a bit hard to detect issue

Comment: @SamvelAleqsanyan I have resaved permalinks - still the same.  will try get assistance from host for server side errors.       thank you